# How can I use the return value of a function in a :set command?

Tags: variables, set

I want to set an option to a string containing full path of current working directory. For example

```
set tags=getcwd()."\tags"    " retrieve the full path of the tags file in current working directory
```

However, vim seems only accept expansion for `let` variables, it don't expand the function in `set` context.

Is there way to achieve expand things in `set`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `:let` with Vim options as well, by prefixing the option name with a `&` sigil; cp. [`:help :let-option`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Alet-option)

```
let &tags = getcwd().'\tags'
```

**Note** that the literal string must be in **single quotes** (or the backslash doubled); else, the `\t` will expand to a tab character.

---

The other way would be by using `:execute`, but then you'd have to take care of escaping, so this is not recommended:

```
execute 'set tags='.escape(getcwd(), '\ ').'\tags'
```