# how to stop vim from shortening window title to terminal width?

Tags: neovim

after some tinkering with xprop and window resizing, I'm almost certain it's (neo)vim, not the terminal emulator or the window manager that's shortening the x11 window title name (one of these x11 window attributes `_NET_WM_ICON_NAME`, `_NET_WM_NAME`, `WM_ICON_NAME`, `WM_NAME`)

specifically it's shortening anything before " - NVIM"

EDIT: I just remembered that useful window names with file name and current directory path is not default behavior, and is enabled with `set title`

Answer (score 2):

it looks like there's no option to configure that, but you can set the title by setting `titlestring` (for more info see `:help titlestring`).

you can set `titlestring` on each buffer enter with:

`autocmd bufenter * let &titlestring = expand('%:p').' - NVIM'`

You use `autocmd bufenter *` to run something on each buffer enter, the asterisk means the file extension doesn't matter,

and use `let` with Vim options by prefixing the option name with a `&` (see `:help :let-option`) <sup>[[1]](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17983/20087)</sup>

and use `expand('%:p')` to get the full path of the file opened in current buffer <sup>[[2]](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/1885/20087)</sup>

Comment: Prefer putting autocmds in augroups